# line graph can not show up using php

Tags: php

The code suppose show the image like this below
[image]

however the result is this below

[image]

this is my code here

**simplegraph.php**

```
<?php
// set up image canvas
$height = 200;
$width = 200;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(width, height)($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
$blue = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 255);

// draw on image
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $blue);
imageline($im, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
imagestring($im, 4, 50, 150, 'Sales', $white);

// output image
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng ($im);

// clean up
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

here is all files in

**htdocs**

[image]

Comment: I suppose show the image that I show above, but it did not

Comment: For the future, it's best to [get errors to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) when debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because of this statement:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(width, height)($width, $height);
```

The above is incorrect syntax. Change this to:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```

The image will show after this, because PHP is assuming, that `width` and `height` are constants, but they do not exist and it will give out error, and after that the `($width, $height)` part will cause the syntax error. But that is the part that you actually need.